# How to extract the console output of an application to the Jenkins console output?

Tags: ant, jenkins, aix, jenkins-plugins

I have an application that runs over AIX platform through Jenkins (AIX is a slave node). When I run the same application over windows I can see all the output of the application over Jenkins' console but when I run the same application over AIX I am not only able to see anything, except what I have defined in ANT script. Is there is any way or any available plugin that allows Jenkins to extract all the output to its console output window. If not, than, is there any way this can be done through ANT.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done through ANT. There is a property called 'spawn', if it is defined and set to false than I can see my output over the Jenkins Console.